# Journals similar to The Mathematical Intelligencer?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, publishing

I confess I am not sure if the following question is appropriate for this S.E.. If not, simply let me know and I will remove it by myself.

As *The American Mathematical Monthly* may be viewed in some sense as an equivalent to *The Mathematical Intelligencer*, I would like to know which journals in existence also share the properties similar to those of *The Mathematical Intelligencer*. Specifically, I would like to know those similar to the journal under consideration in paper quality and the speed of reviewing papers.

Comment: I consider the Mathematical Intelligencer a magazine publication about mathematics, mathematicians, and the history and culture of mathematics, and not a "journal" in the sense of soliciting and reviewing research articles. From [the Springer-Verlag website](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/283): "Note: The traditional Definition/Theorem/Proof style of research articles is not appropriate here, nor are articles aimed only at specialists."

Comment: @hardmath: Thank you for the information. I call it a journal simply because I occasionally see nice "recreational mathematics" papers in its publications. Would you like to recommend few alike magazines?

Comment: I would like to ask similiar question. Are there soma magazines for amateurs interested in math e.g. someonenwha had a lot of contact with math on univesity?

Comment: Try _The Mathematical Gazette_ published by The Mathematical Association (UK).

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: Thanks so much. Actually currently I have one article there, which unfortunately has been processed for almost one year... :) Please do not take my words as against your kindness; your comment is certainly valuable for many others.

Comment: Your comments seem to indicate an interest in submitting papers for publication rather than readership of such publications.  Perhaps the Question should be edited to make the focus of interest clearer, e.g. the nature of papers that you would submit for publication (topics and balance of exposition vs. research).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Go with the *Monthly* if you are very confident in the quality of your manuscript; go with *Math Horizons* if you do not mind taking a more informal tone and possible trimming down your exposition somewhat.

---

I feel compelled to answer this question mostly because of my own experience with the periodicals/magazines/journals in the MAA (which the *American Mathematical Monthly* is a part of). Hopefully my answer will prove useful to you and others.

You wrote the following in a comment:

> Thanks so much. Actually currently I have one article there [*Mathematical Gazette*], which unfortunately has been processed for almost one year.

I understand this frustration well--I submitted a manuscript to the *College Mathematics Journal* (another MAA periodical) in November of 2013. **It is still being processed.** [~ 1.5 years later] What the hell kind of unprofessionalism is that? My article was not even lengthy (9 pages), was perfectly formatted (used their $\rm\LaTeX$ article tample), etc. I finally decided to write the editor. I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1yld.png) response months later (no joke). Just for some context, the MAA is a very professional publication with the following core periodicals:

- [The American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly)
- [Mathematics Magazine](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/mathematics-magazine)
- [The College Mathematics Journal](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal)
- [Math Horizons](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/math-horizons)

The above are listed in terms of what I would consider are the prestige and difficulty of getting your manuscript accepted. The targeted audience is different for each one though. It is very difficult to get a paper accepted into the *Monthly* sometimes simply because of the sheer volume of submissions the MAA gets. At least their issues are current (if you click the link above, you will see their publications are up to date). Both the *Mathematics Magazine* and *College Mathematics Journal* seem to have a huge backlog of unprocessed manuscripts. If you click the links for both of those periodicals, you will see that no content for 2015 has even been listed. That's surprisingly unprofessional, in my opinion, for an organization as professional as the MAA.

All hope is not lost though! While *Math Horizons* is certainly not on the level of the three other periodicals listed, it would still be a very good publication, but you would have to keep your readership in mind. Articles for *Math Horizons* are typically somewhat informal but very high quality--it's a fairly delicate balance to strike. The great thing is that the editor (the current editor is [David Richeson](http://users.dickinson.edu/~richesod/)) will get back to you in a reasonably prompt fashion and, assuming your article is accepted, you can expect it to go to print fairly quickly. I have had two articles published in *Math Horizons*, and I would say my experience overall has been quite positive. However, I would never recommend *Mathematics Magazine* or *The College Mathematics Journal*. It's like throwing your manuscript into a black hole, as it seems you have felt with the *Mathematical Gazette*. If your manuscript is *very* high quality and you do not want to take an informal tone, then the *Monthly* may be a good choice, but you cannot bank on your article being accepted. On the other hand, *Math Horizons* may not carry quite as much prestige, but it would still be a very high quality publication--acceptance is still not guaranteed though, of course, as *Math Horizons* is a very popular periodical for readers of all math levels, and the volume of submissions is enormous.